# OpenVPN works with NetworkManager, but not from terminal?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I've done quite a bit of snooping, and just can't seem to figure this out.  Please go easy on me.

Every time I run OpenVPN from the terminal (via `sudo openvpn --config x.ovpn`), everything seems fine (aside from that warning about credential caching).  But when I `traceroute google.com`, it's not routing through the VPN.

This is not a problem when I connect via `nm-applet`, and NetworkManager's configuration was auto-generated from OpenVPN's config file.

I checked `ip route` with each of these methods, and only when I use the GUI does it add another default route:

```
default via <address> dev <device> proto static metric 50
```

I tried the following, to no avail:

- enabling forwarding via `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
- adding a new default route via: `ip route add default via <gateway> dev <device>`

---

I'm fairly sure that NetworkManager's not directly calling the `openvpn` command (took a look at the source), though it's certainly adding a new default route that `openvpn` is not.

Am I on the right track, and if not, could someone please point me in the right direction?

---

EDIT:

I managed to route all traffic through `<device>`, but it was very messy.  Does anyone know the commands NetworkManager issues to modify the routing tables when using OpenVPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clean way around the issue: using `vpnfailsafe`.

I installed it from my repos, and added the following to my config file:

```
up <path-to-vpnfailsafe.sh>
down <path-to-vpnfailsafe.sh>
script-security 2
```